# Electrolytes are ionic compounds that conduct electricity

Tags: physical-chemistry, everyday-chemistry, electrochemistry

Electrolytes are ionic compounds that conduct electricity, or the flow of charged particles, when dissolved in water. This occurs via the separated ions acting as those charged particles, or charge carriers, when a voltage is applied. Which compound would not create an electrolyte solution when dissolved in water?

A) ammonium acetate, $\ce{NH4C2H3O2}$

B) sucrose, $\ce{C12H22O11}$

c) sodium hydroxide, $\ce{NaOH}$

D) potassium nitrate, $\ce{KNO3}$

Comment: You have to improve your questions because it looks like homework.Most likely your future questions will get flagged.Write the problem you are having when you are asking a question.

Comment: Welcome to Chem.SE. For these questions, can you show us and edit in your way of approaching the question so we can help you better? Because what you said sems like you just copy from a textbook and not understanding what it means

Answer (score 1):

Sucrose is an covalent compound and it does not ionize.
$\ce{KNO3}$, $\ce{NaOH}$ are good ionic compounds hence the can form electolytic solutions.
Ammonium acetate also can ionize.
Hence the answer is 2

Comment: Hey! It's not a hw question, its asking about Which compound would not create an electrolyte solution when dissolved in water

Comment: We have a policy which states that ‎you should show your thoughts and/or efforts into solving the problem. It'll make us certain that ‎we aren't doing your homework for you. 
Basically any question with the wording your question has is considered homework; it needn't be literally one. Self-study questions, puzzles etc. also count as homework. 

Don't worry, they're not banned. But, we require a minimal effort. 
Otherwise, this question may get closed.‎ Please [edit] in your full reasoning or thoughts on this.

See [homework](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/141/7448)